# automatically set xrange in gnuplot

Tags: range, gnuplot

Is there any way to set automaticaly xrange in gnuplot base on how many lines have my datafile ?
I tried autoscale but it still let me few centimeters of free space at the end of my plot.
I mean something like

```
set xrange ["0":"EOF"]
```

datafile sample:

```
0|18:33:56|5.6094713|-2.5295162|0.05702305
1|18:33:56|5.506433|-1.9757175|0.25703526
2|18:33:56|5.7228355|-1.7813735|0.59802055
3|18:33:56|5.8039265|-1.6758609|0.97007275
4|18:33:56|5.675423|-1.581326|1.2965202
5|18:33:56|5.3796544|-1.4743104|1.4236889
```

Can I put some mark at the end of datafile and set it in gnuplot or ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a tightly fitted xrange, use

```
set autoscale xfix
```

Comment: Tnaks this is what i needed ;)

Answer (score 4):

If your gnuplot's version is 4.6 or later, you can use `stats` command

```
stats 'datafile' using 1
set xrange [0:STATS_records]
```

You can also use other statistical variables such as STATS_min, STATS_max.
For more information, type `help stats` in your gnuplot's prompt.

Comment: I think it should work as I tested with my data. You can check it by `print STATS_records` or `print STATS_min` in gnuplot's prompt after the `stats` command. Of course the answer of @Christoph is much better.